# Are shopping malls open in Washington DC and nearby areas during the holidays?

Tags: shopping, public-holidays, washington-dc, opening-hours

I am going to Washington DC and Virginia on the 28th of December. I will be staying for three days.

Will the malls be open normally during these days? For example, Tysons Corner mall.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shopping malls in and around DC (and everywhere else stateside) will be in full swing starting 26 December to about close of play on 31 December.

This would include [Tysons Corner](http://www.tysonscornercenter.com/), and if you do not arrive early you can expect to have to use [fringe parking](http://www.tysonscornercenter.com/Visit/GettingHere#parking).

Shops at Tysons will be open from 10AM to 9:30PM, 1000 to 2130.  You will also be able to take ice skating lessons at the rink and on 27 December you will have a chance to meet the [Washington Capitals Street Team and Slapshot](http://www.tysonscornercenter.com/Events/Details/412124?startDate=12/27/2015&back=).  Barnes and Noble will also have special events throughout the week.

Comment: The link does not seem to support all of your assertions.  In particular, I didn't see anything about fringe parking, nor about the Washington Capitals.  Did I overlook something or do you have another source for this information?

Comment: @phoog, for the Washington Capitals events, please see the listing at http://www.tysonscornercenter.com/Events  Also, my suggestion about fringe parking comes from lengthy personal experience.

Comment: I am living in the general area of Tyson's and I can affirm that all next week (After Christmas) Tyson's main parking lots will be quite full up. You'll end up parking out at the outer edge, or fringe of the lots, unless you are very very lucky.

Comment: Another way to avoid the parking issue (which is genuine): the Washington Metro Silver Line serves Tysons Corner.